# What is this new feature "questions with no upvoted answers" for?

Tags: support, questions, unanswered-questions

I have recently seen this **"questions with no upvoted answers"** on the right top corner of my Stack Overflow page.

Just wanted to know what was the intention for introducing this feature?

Is it for the answerers to reach the questions quickly to earn more reputation? Or something else behind it?

Comment: "Is it for the answerers to reach the questions quickly to earn more reputation?" Why am I not surprised at this guess?

Comment: This is not a new feature... I've been using this for years.

Comment: Probably not the easy rep in there, but questions that are *hard* to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all this is not a new feature. [This is the list](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) where you find questions having *no answers* or *no upvoted answers*.

Remember it is different from [questions with *no answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers).

The intention of both tabs is to help questions which are still not answered or not answered well.